Manipulate import urls after build in ViteJS
I have a react application configured with ViteJs (vite and @vitejs/plugin-react).
I Managed to change base path and it works correctly (I see <script src="/panel/client/assets/index-BHlWjozO.js"></script> inside index.html after build)
const config = {
    ...,
    base: `/panel/customer`,
    .
    .
    .
}

But for the imported stuff it doesn't work.
For example, inside my css files i have imported fonts like url(/fonts/font.ttf) and after build i expect it to be url(/panel/customer/fonts/font.ttf) instead.
Or for images as an example, if i have an img element with this src:
<img src="/sample.png" />
i expect it's src to be /panel/customer/sample.png after build.
I know that i can handle this inside my source codes. But i don't want to do that for some reasons.
I have to handle import links after build time by one of these ways:

some rollup plugins that can do this
some vite plugins that can do this
iterate over all import links and change them manually by some rollup or vite plugins
some rollup or vite options for that
anything but changing source code (i can change vite config only)


can you change package.json? you can try setting base path in build script

yes i can. can you provide an example?

like this "build": "vite build --base=/panel/customer". I am replying too late, so hopefully you have figured out the solution.
